# "Crop Dusting" Achievement as a melee class?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

The achievement in question involves killing Ghom, Lord of Gluttony (in act III) without getting hit by his gas attack.

Ghom uses this area of effect gas attack in melee a lot, and I don't seem to be able to predict when or how often he will use it. This makes avoiding the attack as a melee character problematic.

Does anyone have a strategy for how to get this achievement as a melee class? Does he have a "tell" that he is about to use his gas? Or do I need to kite him while throwing axes/tornados (which will be incredibly slow).
My characters are a Barbarian and a Monk.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I did it on my monk by only attacking him immediately after he did it and I'd kited him out of it, after a few seconds of attacking, I'd kite him again until he gassed again, kite him out and start attacking again, repeat as necessary. He probably does have a tell though.

Comment: In order to get all the achivements you need to create and use all classes anyway. So I would not even bother trying to get it with a melee char.

Comment: Seconding what @ayckoster commented.  I did it easily (and accidentally) in NM with my wizard.  Given achievements are across your account, I'd just run a ranged character to Act III normal if you really want it.

Comment: I understand that it would be easier to do it as a ranged class. And I plan to level some of them. But I wanted to know if there was any good way of doing on the classes I have.

The problem with running out every "few seconds" is that you still sometimes get hit by the gas, because that is based on luck. I've tried that.

Comment: Equip a bow and use your basic attack.

Comment: The Monk's Deadly Reach is pretty long-ranged, and the Foresight rune makes it deal and incredible amount of damage. Try it out!

Comment: @NiQAlasT: Neither Monk nor Barb can equip a bow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Level 34 barbarian (middle of act 4, normal difficulty, my first run) can kill monster power 0 normal difficulty Ghom with several uses of "Ancient spear" (doesn't require fury and generates some) and "Weapon throw" (uses little fury) skills and a minute or two running.

Answer (score 5):

You're going to have difficulty doing this with a melee class character. There are 2 options and it's going to be easier if you do both of them.

1. Get yourself a ranged character (Demon Hunter is my favourite) and
   kite Ghom
2. Use a Hell difficulty character in Normal mode and you should be able to one hit him.

Answer (score 1):

The other option as a melee is play with people online and get them to kill the boss without you really doing anything to the boss. The bosses are usually easy, for most groups especially at the later levels as it is really the elite monster groups that are the threat.

Answer (score 1):

I did this with a barb.  Get to level 60, use unforgiving (gain fury rather than lose it), weapon throw + mighty throw rune, make sure you have full fury and decent strength, fight Ghom on normal, and stand back and use weapon throw.  Took me 2-3 hits.

Comment: Also used this setup for the antivenom achievement.